# gitlab kaniko - No matching credentials were found, falling back on anonymous

Tags: docker, kubernetes, gitlab-ci, kaniko

I'm using kaniko image to push an image to a private docker register, and it gives me `No matching credentials were found, falling back on anonymous`.

```
docker run  -v $PWD:/workspace \
        -v /root/.docker/config.json:/kaniko/config.json \
        --env DOCKER_CONFIG=/kaniko \
        gcr.io/kaniko-project/executor:latest \
        -d gitlab.xxx.org/xxx/xxx
```

the config.json file is valid as I verified with docker login
I aslo follow [kaniko gitlab](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_kaniko.html) to run kaniko in k8s, and get the same error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed, It's just about image download. I'm using it in an internal network. It's not about pushing images to registery.